# IE 7 and 8 doesn't recognize jQuery's height and width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I wrote a couple of functions using `config` variable. Here's how it looks like:

```
scripts = function() {
    var config = {
        windowWidth: $(window).width(),
        windowHeight: $(window).height()
    }

    function generatePages() {
        $('section.main').each(function() {
            $(this).css({
                'width' : config.windowWidth,
                'height': config.windowHeight
            });

            if($(this).children('.more').length) {
                $(this).children('.more').css('line-height',config.windowHeight+'px')
            }
        });
    }

    return {
        config:config,
        generatePages:generatePages
    }
}();

scripts.generatePages();
```

It works OK in all browsers, but IE 7-9 doesn't run `generatePages`, it seems it doesn't "understand" `$(window).width()` and `height()`. What can I do?

Comment: i guess there are missing commas or semi-colons. IE is very sensitive about this.

Comment: Are you running it too early in the page loading cycle?  Are you seeing any browser errors in the console?

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: Have you debugged at all? `alert` or `console.log` variables and outputs at different stages?

Comment: Does `$('body').width()` work instead of `$(window).width()`?

Comment: I did debug, console is clear.

Comment: which jQuery version are you using?

Comment: Stefan, no.
Leon, 2.0.3.

Comment: A [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be nice btw :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you commented on my question you're using jQuery 2.0.3, you can not use jQuery 2+ in older browsers:

**As promised, this version leaves behind the older Internet Explorer 6, 7, and 8 browsers. In return it is smaller, faster, and can be used in JavaScript environments where the code needed for old-IE compatibility often causes problems of its own. But don’t worry, the jQuery team still supports the 1.x branch which does run on IE 6/7/8. You can (and should) continue to use jQuery 1.9 (and the upcoming 1.10) on web sites that need to accommodate older browsers.**

source: http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/

Answer (score 0):

Try it adding the `px` measure:

```
$(this).css({
    'width': config.windowWidth + 'px',
    'height': config.windowHeight + 'px'
});
```

Comment: Excellent find and guess.  `.width()` is unitless.  `.css()` requires units.